# How do I remove the divider between Toolbar and TabLayout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-tablayout

I got a tablayout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"/>
```

and a toolbar but there is still a small line between the toolbar and the divider. I haven't set a toolbar style yet. How do I remove the divider?

[heres an image of the divider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNiwZ.jpg)

Comment: Set the same color of the toolbar and the tablayout and it will no be visible I guess

Comment: @Vucko They have the same color, thats why theres only a small divider

Comment: On what API level? I had a similar thing on my phone API 17, where the divider was not visible, and it was on another phone API 21 or so.

Comment: Here is its solution...                   https://stackoverflow.com/a/56998158/7402328

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please update your style.xml with that

```
 <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
```

Comment: added all that to my apptheme, didnt change anything

Comment: added an image of how the divider looks

Comment: Please check out this example                                                                [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/)

Answer (score 5):

Just add `app:elevation="0dp"` in your AppBarLayout Widget `[android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout]` which has a toolbar wrapped.
It will do the work!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

You can check whether that site create toolbar & tablayout

also u can trying with removing "android:elevation" tag.

Answer (score 0):

Add `app:elevation="0dp"` in your `AppBarLayout` widget like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/NavStyle">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ToolbarStyle" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```